# Encryption Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range

Tags: java

I had an encryption in C# I tried porting to Java.

First of all, to generate a secretkey this is the C# code:

```
int keyLength = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond).Next(60, 65);
Random v = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond + DateTime.Now.Second + keyLength);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(keyLength);

for (int i = 0; i < keyLength; i++)
{
    int j = 0;
    if (v.Next(0, 2) == 1)
        j = v.Next(97, 123);
    else
        j = v.Next(48, 58);

    sb.Append((char)j);
}

return sb.ToString();
```

Now, my Java code:

```
int keyLength = new SharpRandom((int)System.currentTimeMillis()).next(60, 65);
SharpRandom rnd = new SharpRandom((int)(System.currentTimeMillis() + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000) + keyLength));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(keyLength);

for (int i = 0; i < keyLength; i++) {
    int j = 0; 

if (rnd.next(0, 2) == 1) {
    j = rnd.next(97, 123);
}
else {
    j = rnd.next(48, 58);
}

builder.append((char)j);
}
```

Now, this is not everything. The SharpRandom is basically a part of the Random.cs of C# ported. Here's code:

```
package com.habbo.torn;

public class SharpRandom {

final int big = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
final int seed = 161803398;

int inext, inextp;
int[] seedarr = new int[56];

public SharpRandom() {
    this((int)System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public SharpRandom(int seed) {
    int i, j, k;

    if (seed == this.big) { 
        j = this.seed - Math.abs(this.big + 1);
    }
    else {
        j = this.seed - Math.abs(seed);
    }

    this.seedarr[55] = j;

    k = 1;

    for (int a = 1; a < 55; a++) {
        i = (21 * a) % 55;

        this.seedarr[i] = k;
        k = j - k;

        if (k < 0) {
            k += this.big;
        }

        j = this.seedarr[i];
    }

    for (int b = 1; b < 5; b++) {
        for (int c = 1; c < 56; c++) {
            this.seedarr[c] -= this.seedarr[1 + (c + 30) % 55];
            if (this.seedarr[c] < 0)
                this.seedarr[c] += this.big;
        }
    }

    inext = 0;
    inextp = 31;
}

public double sample() {
    int retVal;

    if (++inext  >= 56) inext  = 1;
    if (++inextp >= 56) inextp = 1;

    retVal = this.seedarr[inext] - this.seedarr[inextp];

    if (retVal < 0) {
        retVal += this.big;
    }

    this.seedarr[inext] = retVal;

    return retVal * (1.0 / this.big);
}

public int next(int min, int max) {
    int diff = (int) (max - min);

    if (diff <= 1) {
        return min;
    }

    return (int)((sample () * diff) + min);
}

}
```

So, I use my RC4 class, the C# version had 2 classes but I just put them together (useless to make 2 classes), I'll give code, but I'm gonna paste in pastebin since it's over 800 lines of codes (the original coder of the C# class made for every int in the int-array another line).

http://pastebin.com/AiF6WJdV

And now the other class:

http://pastebin.com/ae4z56S4

Now, I tried porting it to Java:

```
package com.habbo.torn;

public class RC4 {

private final String di[] = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" };
private final int keyWindow[] = { 204, 53, 74, 109, 63, 4, 163, 182, 210, 186, 19, 162, 160, 115, 139, 83, 235, 177, 14, 15, 11, 127, 4, 210, 222, 138, 10, 138, 151, 236, 158, 186, 67, 1, 168, 69, 139, 214, 243, 32, 157, 161, 211, 155, 20, 192, 214, 155, 12, 153, 192, 112,98, 146, 33, 30, 22, 131, 81, 161, 105, 142, 103, 204, 112, 9, 167, 185, 176, 51, 27, 166, 249, 228, 24, 165, 197, 25, 166, 216, 74, 14, 104, 15, 77, 49, 6, 50, 65, 126, 10, 187, 15, 17, 189, 155, 246, 221, 92, 104, 79, 87, 186, 88, 80, 50, 223, 126, 148, 217, 81, 223, 91, 70, 165, 237, 150, 95, 195, 205, 199, 176, 156, 122, 187, 232, 252, 230, 169, 94, 157, 194, 44, 164, 208, 22, 141, 139, 167, 236, 201, 42, 130, 14, 44, 57, 253, 224, 130, 118, 242, 226, 146, 202, 154, 40, 201, 171, 160, 91, 143, 144, 150, 197, 169, 204, 121, 131, 139, 112, 214, 196, 74, 123, 159, 220, 77, 176, 151, 73, 125, 135, 166, 26, 176, 31, 255, 234, 91, 30, 218, 41, 121, 17, 45, 3, 234, 35, 185, 52, 112, 108, 65, 72, 184, 93, 225, 113, 62, 0, 110, 38, 43, 15, 44, 114, 162, 167, 69, 40, 103, 144, 114, 215, 228, 47, 112, 235, 179, 211, 116, 237, 70, 167, 36, 224, 183, 11, 0, 74, 145, 241, 153,40, 151, 211, 231, 199, 235, 176, 109, 95, 160, 141, 137, 236, 39, 17, 246, 97,120, 227, 12, 1, 195, 239, 150, 169, 85, 226, 23, 58, 145, 157, 37, 218, 132, 168, 94, 15, 240, 24, 152, 230, 249, 80, 145, 208, 209, 144, 154, 228, 197, 40, 6, 248, 90, 15, 1, 82, 145, 77, 220, 27, 167, 0, 149, 0, 103, 53, 226, 242, 175, 9, 177, 130, 65, 216, 107, 4, 194, 71, 135, 231, 151, 178, 188, 220, 33, 152, 120, 165, 73, 124, 32, 215, 127, 130, 29, 40, 20, 3, 212, 254, 106, 42, 98, 7, 8, 129, 195, 30, 74, 118, 169, 81, 88, 235, 149, 232, 181, 182, 206, 82, 163, 26, 116, 37, 41, 50, 63, 185, 165, 2, 81, 10, 149, 103, 211, 168, 34, 55, 32, 233, 16, 238, 219, 235, 170, 255, 244, 12, 89, 211, 88, 33, 24, 38, 190, 75, 70, 86, 89, 2, 189, 134, 207, 65, 6, 148, 124, 22, 57, 21, 118, 227, 173, 21, 236, 236, 139, 189, 230, 153, 153, 182, 230, 216, 26, 0, 9, 50, 32, 189, 97, 3, 208, 201, 103, 163, 96, 0, 42, 11, 173, 98, 102, 76, 31, 243, 59, 71, 223, 252, 186, 157, 231, 90, 212, 83, 10, 69, 69, 165, 209, 112, 157, 237, 24, 90, 4, 44, 247, 32, 159, 126, 171, 99, 216, 196, 228, 217, 157, 143, 32, 16, 111, 67, 106, 231, 10, 167, 13, 240, 182, 105, 52, 12, 84, 91, 243, 205, 180, 180, 35, 58, 238, 240, 0, 209, 48, 249, 243, 209, 93, 10, 22, 183, 5, 177, 110, 16, 188, 201, 240, 194, 11, 76, 219, 67, 254, 176, 139, 66, 81, 138, 109, 178, 71, 143, 74, 217, 52, 0, 127,190, 12, 214, 231, 84, 239, 165, 155, 89, 95, 106, 62, 30, 182, 137, 85, 39, 221, 51, 188, 149, 104, 167, 71, 11, 220, 212, 246, 114, 10, 4, 216, 127, 233, 231, 178, 174, 181, 29, 49, 118, 177, 108, 156, 174, 118, 196, 216, 106, 203, 96, 65, 12, 140, 248, 152, 35, 152, 17, 89, 136, 138, 94, 5, 190, 92, 189, 16, 216, 61, 70, 165, 36, 238, 167, 16, 61, 206, 140, 226, 251, 37, 225, 211, 111, 42, 195, 36, 248, 233, 67, 146, 100, 244, 23, 154, 103, 48, 4, 15, 33, 169, 151, 13, 151, 115, 173, 37, 103, 172, 23, 182, 29, 22, 25, 54, 46, 188, 14, 24, 12, 182, 241, 163, 90, 121, 172, 29, 73, 191, 91, 232, 229, 197, 200, 32, 7, 67, 214, 141, 248, 10, 135, 168, 4, 144, 17, 94, 228, 76, 202, 130, 174, 251, 170, 100, 173, 232, 183, 132, 130, 35, 163, 1, 154, 134, 56, 202, 13, 190, 224, 56, 107, 107, 244, 16, 12, 149, 220, 120, 245, 179, 103, 85, 255, 195, 187, 191, 82, 225, 13, 206, 106, 60, 212, 12, 211, 247, 112, 185, 5, 56, 226, 236, 179, 181, 208, 204, 16, 159, 158, 36, 65, 101, 148, 23, 89, 125, 27, 61, 117, 255, 142, 32, 138, 105, 166, 203, 253, 113, 138, 30, 247, 250, 198, 21, 244, 113, 40, 161, 229, 179, 100, 76, 30, 177, 69, 87, 90, 9, 135, 254, 108, 99, 145, 195, 145, 138, 223, 237, 52, 126, 244, 109, 171, 44, 0, 187, 129, 127, 49, 220, 100, 253, 0, 116, 93, 87, 39, 245, 5, 54, 203, 241, 155, 255, 125, 80, 253, 75, 71, 242, 147, 153, 148, 214, 91, 33, 181, 78, 10, 82, 171, 89, 179, 221, 144, 224, 138, 112, 254, 152, 186, 190, 224, 44, 251, 60, 133, 65, 70, 72, 203, 126, 123, 212, 108, 68, 185, 42, 208, 51, 11, 177, 3, 24, 207, 14, 148, 113, 55, 1, 19, 179, 31, 133, 11, 227, 72, 145, 242, 157, 244, 239, 129, 124, 109, 56, 134, 56, 95, 110, 161, 73, 151, 136, 67, 176, 201, 193, 70, 53, 31, 238, 84, 81, 65, 50, 182, 20, 17, 247, 179, 217, 14, 34, 182, 97, 55, 117, 176, 108, 234, 147, 89, 168, 7, 251, 212, 22, 107, 63, 248, 179, 222, 167, 214, 136, 74, 53, 47, 120, 233, 131, 41, 167, 220, 56, 12, 51, 125, 207, 112, 179, 211, 47, 134, 223, 112, 223, 46, 249, 24, 64, 58, 36,187, 77, 132, 116, 116, 111, 36, 127, 217, 177, 24, 58, 102, 166, 105, 119, 234, 187, 198, 77, 153, 23, 157, 103, 92, 33, 136, 182, 131, 154, 141, 149, 4, 117,213, 226, 64, 116, 55, 6, 159, 126, 225 }; 
private final String premixString = "eb11nmhdwbn733c2xjv1qln3ukpe0hvce0ylr02s12sv96rus2ohexr9cp8rufbmb1mdb732j1l3kehc0l0s2v6u2hx9prfmu";

private int i;
private int j;

private int[] key = new int[256];
private int[] table = new int[256];

public RC4(String key) {
    this.i = 0;
    this.j = 0;

    this.initialize(this.decodeKey(key));
    this.premixTable(this.premixString);
}

public void initialize(String decodedKey) {
    int key = Integer.parseInt(decodedKey);
    int length = (key & 248) / 8;

    if (length < 20) {
        length += 20;
    }

    int offset = key & this.keyWindow.length;
    int given = key;
    int own = 0;

    int[] w = new int[length];

    for (int a = 0; a < length; a++) {
        own = this.keyWindow[Math.abs((offset + a) % this.keyWindow.length)];
        w[a] = Math.abs(given ^ own);

        if (a == 31) {
            given = key;
        }
        else {
            given = (given / 2);
        }
    }

    for (int b = 0; b < 256; b++) {
        this.key[b] = w[b % w.length];
        this.table[b] = b;
    }

    int t = 0;
    int u = 0;

    for (int c = 0; c < 256; c++) {
        u = ((u + this.table[c] + this.key[c]) % 256);
        t = this.table[c];
        this.table[c] = this.table[u];
        this.table[u] = t;
    }
}

private void premixTable(String s) {
    for (int a = 0; a < 17; i++) {
        this.encipher(s);
    }
}

public String encipher(String s) {
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder(s.length() * 2);

    int t = 0;
    int k = 0;

    for (int a = 0; a < s.length(); a++) {
        this.i = (this.i + 1) % 256;
        this.j = (this.j + this.table[this.i]) % 256;

        t = this.table[this.i];

        this.table[this.i] = this.table[this.j];
        this.table[this.j] = t;

        k = this.table[(this.table[this.i] + this.table[this.j]) % 256];

        int c = s.substring(a, 1).toCharArray()[0] ^ k;

        if (c <= 0) {
            ret.append("00");
        }
        else {
            ret.append(this.di[c >> 4 & 15]);
            ret.append(this.di[c & 15]);
        }
    }

    return ret.toString();
}

public String decodeKey(String Key) {
    String table = Key.substring(0, Key.length() / 2);
    String key = Key.substring(Key.length() / 2);

    long checkSum = 0L;

    for (int i = 0; i < table.length(); i++) {
        int offset = table.indexOf(key.substring(i, 1));

        if (offset % 2 == 0) {
            offset *= 2;
        }

        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            offset *= 3;
        }

        if (offset < 0) {
            offset = table.length() % 2;
        }

        checkSum += offset;
        checkSum ^= offset << (i % 3) * 8;
    }

    return Long.toString(checkSum);
}

public byte[] decipher(String data) {
    StringBuilder end = new StringBuilder(data.length());

    int t = 0; 
    int k = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        this.i = (this.i + 1) % 256;
        this.j = (this.j + this.table[this.i]) % 256;

        t = this.table[this.i];

        this.table[this.i] = this.table[this.j];
        this.table[this.j] = t;

        k = this.table[(this.table[this.i] + this.table[this.j]) % 256];
        t = Integer.parseInt(data.substring(i, i + 2), 16);

        end = end.append((char) (t ^ k));
    }

    return end.toString().getBytes();
}

}
```

Ok.. almost done. So what I need to do, generate the key with first code I posted (secretkey), then create new instance of the RC4 class (rc4provider C# class), with the secretkey.

What happens however is, if I try to do it, I get:

```
Initializing Encryption..
Set secretKey as oopjjpnlob4r9y4734igzjn1w31014gnaeb8ry60jufreun92y6t1f162xh6l
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

The line of error:

```
int offset = table.indexOf(key.substring(i, 1));
```

I hope somebody can help me, I really need it. Thanks already.

Comment: Your PRNG is not cryptographically strong.  Use the builtin `java.util.SecureRandom` instead.

Comment: I converted Random.cs to Java, that's why I won't use SecureRandom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29) method in Java takes a beginning index (inclusive) and an ending index (exclusive), not a desired substring length.

Try

```
int offset = table.indexOf(key.substring(i, i + 1));
```

Quoting the Javadocs I linked above:

> Throws: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the beginIndex is negative, or
>   endIndex is larger than the length of this String object, or
>   beginIndex is larger than endIndex.

Looking at the source code, it does throw a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  It says it throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, but a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.